# Find the eigenvalues of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, diagonalization, symmetric-matrices

> Let   $a_1, a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_n   \in \mathbb{R}$ be  such that $a_1 +
>  a_2 +\cdots+a_n = 0$ and  denote
>
> $$A=\left(\begin{matrix}    a_1^2 +1  & a_1a_2+1 & \cdots & a_1a_n
>  +1 \\   a_2a_1+1 & a_2^2+1 & \cdots & a_2a_n +1 \\ \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\ a_na_1 + 1 & a_na_2 + 1
>  & \cdots & a_n^2 +1 \\ \end{matrix}\right)$$
>
> Find the  eigenvalues  of $A$

My attempts  :  first  I take $ n = 2$ then  i got $A = \begin{bmatrix} a_1^2 +1 &a_1a_2 + 1 \\ a_2a_1 &a_2^2 + 1 \end{bmatrix}$

now  finding the  eigenvalue  of $A  - \lambda  I =0$ then$$ A - \lambda I= \begin{bmatrix} a_1^2 +1-\lambda &a_1a_2 + 1 \\ a_2a_1 &a_2^2 + 1 - \lambda\end{bmatrix} $$

$$(a_1^2 +1-\lambda)(a_2^2 + 1 - \lambda)-a_1^2a_2^2 -a_1a_2 =0$$

Here  I find difficulty in finding the  eigenvalues  of  $A$.

Plase, help me.

Any hints/solution will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure the term in left corner should be $a_2a_1$? Since every single term of this kind has the form $a_na_1+1$ it would be logical if this term would be $a_2a_1+1$.

Comment: Which terms below the main diagonal get $+1$ ?

Comment: @mrtaurho yes  the left corner is $a_2a_1$

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit,,im not getting  ,,,can u elaborate more

Comment: @stupid Okay. That is odd but an important fact. I just wanted to make it clear.

Comment: Assuming there should be +1 for $a_2a_1$, then you can write it as $A=11^T + aa^T$

Comment: @mathreadler  what is  a  ?  i mean  what is the value of  a ....not getting

Comment: @stupid  Go back and read again the problem statement wherever you got it from.  Check whether you copied your problem correctly here.  We suspect a typo.  Nobody wants to invest much time helping you yet because of the suspected typo.

Comment: @stupid $a$ would be a column vector storing the $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$. But do as Batominovski says and double check you wrote the question right. My hint will only work if there is an extra +1 in the spot.

Comment: @Batominovski...that  is   correct ...i have  taken from linear algebra(challenging problem for students)  fuzhen zhang books..page N0 . 60  and problem 3.52

Comment: Then, that is very odd.  We don't know which term has $+1$, which term doesn't.  So, either the typo starts from there, or F. Zhang did not write the problem statement very well (i.e., he did not clarify where $+1$ should be).

Comment: @Batominovski I just checked this by myself within the book online and I only can say that the term is $a_2a_1$ and not $a_2a_1+1$. Additionally there is the task *Show that $A=BB^t$ for some matrix $B$* denoted. [It is a little bit hard to read but you can see through : https://de.scribd.com/doc/111429137/Linear-Algebra-Challenging-Problems-for-Students-Fuzhen-Zhang-1]

Comment: Then it is a typo in the book. Because this is indeed a $BB^T$ with $+1$

Comment: @mrtaurho If $A$ is supposed to be written in the form $BB^\top$, then it has to be symmetric.  So, percusse is right.  The matrix shown here in the OP's statement is not symmetric.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As discussed in the comment section, we believe that the problem comes with a typo and the correct matrix is
$$\mathbf{A}=\begin{bmatrix}
a_1^2+1&a_1a_2+1&a_1a_3+1&\cdots&a_1a_n+1\\
a_2a_1+1&a_2^2+1&a_2a_3+1&\cdots&a_2a_n+1\\
a_3a_1+1&a_3a_2+1&a_3^2+1&\cdots&a_3a_n+1\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
a_na_1+1&a_na_2+1&a_na_3+1&\cdots&a_n^2+1
\end{bmatrix}=\boldsymbol{1}\,\boldsymbol{1}^\top+\boldsymbol{a}\,\boldsymbol{a}^\top\,,$$
where $\boldsymbol{1}:=(\underbrace{1,1,1,\ldots,1}_{n\text{ ones}})$ and $\boldsymbol{a}:=(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_n)$.  I shall provide a generalization below.  From this generalization, we conclude that the eigenvalues of this matrix are $n,\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\,a_k^2,\underbrace{0,0,\ldots,0}_{n-2\text{ zeros}}$.

If $\boldsymbol{a}$ is nonzero, then respective eigenvectors are $\boldsymbol{1},\boldsymbol{a},\boldsymbol{b}_1,\boldsymbol{b}_2,\ldots,\boldsymbol{b}_{n-2}$, where $\boldsymbol{b}_1,\boldsymbol{b}_2,\ldots,\boldsymbol{b}_{n-2}$ are any $n-2$ linearly independent vectors orthogonal (in the usual sense) to both $\boldsymbol{1}$ and $\boldsymbol{a}$ (they exist since the map $\boldsymbol{\varphi}:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^2$ sending $\boldsymbol{c}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\big(\langle\boldsymbol{c},\boldsymbol{1}\rangle,\langle\boldsymbol{c},\boldsymbol{a}\rangle\big)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ is a linear map of rank $2$, where $\langle\_,\_\rangle$ is the usual inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$).  If $\boldsymbol{a}$ is the zero vector, then there are $n-1$ linearly independent vectors $\boldsymbol{b}_1,\boldsymbol{b}_2,\ldots,\boldsymbol{b}_{n-1}$ orthogonal to $\boldsymbol{1}$, and respective eigenvectors are then $\boldsymbol{1},\boldsymbol{b}_1,\boldsymbol{b}_2,\ldots,\boldsymbol{b}_{n-1}$.

---

> **Lemma.**  Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field and $n$ a positive integer.  The vector field $V:=\mathbb{K}^n$ is equipped with the usual nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form $\langle\_,\_\rangle$ defined by
>   $$\big\langle (u^1,u^2,\ldots,u^n),(v^1,v^2,\ldots,v^n)\big\rangle:=u_1v_1+u_2v_2+\ldots+u_nv_n$$
>   for all $u^1,u^2,\ldots,u^n,v^1,v^2,\ldots,v^n\in\mathbb{K}$.  For a nonnegative integer $m$, suppose that $\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2,\ldots,\mathbf{x}_m$ are linearly independent vectors in $V$, which are *mutually orthogonal*, namely, $\langle \mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{x}_j\rangle =0$ for all $i,j\in\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$ with $i\neq j$.  Write $\lambda_k:=\langle \mathbf{x}_k,\mathbf{x}_k\rangle$ for $k=1,2,\ldots,m$.  Let $\xi_1,\xi_2,\ldots,\xi_m$ be arbitrary nonzero scalars (elements of $\mathbb{K}$).  Then, the matrix $$\mathbf{X}=\sum_{k=1}^m\,\xi_k\,\mathbf{x}_k\,\mathbf{x}_k^\top$$ is of rank $m$ with eigenvalues $\xi_1\lambda_1,\xi_2\lambda_2,\ldots,\xi_m\lambda_m,\underbrace{0,0,\ldots,0}_{n-m\text{ zeros}}$.

First, we see that $\mathbf{X}$ has rank $m$ (in this paragraph, mutual orthogonality of $\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2,\ldots,\mathbf{x}_m$ is not used).  To show this, we define $W$ to be the subspace of $V$ spanned by $\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2,\ldots,\mathbf{x}_m$.  Thus, $\dim_\mathbb{K}(W)=m$.  Take the linear functional $\psi_k:V\to\mathbb{K}$ to be the map sending $\mathbf{v}\mapsto \langle \mathbf{v},\mathbf{x}_k\rangle$ for each $k=1,2,\ldots,m$ and $\mathbf{v}\in V$.  These linear functionals are linearly independent element of the dual space $V^*$ of $V$ because $\langle\_,\_\rangle$ is a nondegenerate bilinear form.  In particular, there exist $\mathbf{w}_1,\mathbf{w}_2,\ldots,\mathbf{w}_m\in V$ such that $\psi_i(\mathbf{w}_j)=\delta_{i,j}$ for every $i,j=1,2,\ldots,m$, where $\delta$ is the Kronecker delta.  Therefore,  $\mathbf{X}\,\mathbf{w}_k=\xi_k\,\mathbf{x}_k$ for every $k=1,2,\ldots,m$.  This means $\text{im}(\mathbf{X})=W$, whence $\mathbf{X}$ is a matrix of rank $m$ over $\mathbb{K}$.

Without loss of generality, we can rearrange $\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2,\ldots,\mathbf{x}_m$ so that, for some nonnegative integer $r\leq m$, $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_r$ are nonzero, whereas $\lambda_{r+1},\lambda_{r+2},\ldots,\lambda_{m}$ are zero.  Observe that, for each integer $t\geq 2$,
$$\mathbf{X}^t=\sum_{k=1}^r\,\xi_k^t\lambda_k^{t-1}\,\mathbf{x}_k\,\mathbf{x}_k^\top\,.$$
Using the same argument as before, we determine that $\mathbf{X}^t$ has rank $r$ for every $t=2,3,\ldots$.  That is, $0$ is an eigenvalue of $\mathbf{X}$ with multiplicity exacly $n-r$.

For the remaining part, we just determine $r$ eigenvectors of $\mathbf{X}$ corresponding to the nonzero eigenvalues $\xi_1\lambda_1,\xi_2\lambda_2,\ldots,\xi_r\lambda_r$.  This is easy, as $\mathbf{X}\,\mathbf{x}_k=\xi_k\lambda_k\,\mathbf{x}_k$ for all $k=1,2,\ldots,m$, recalling that $\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2,\ldots,\mathbf{x}_m$ are mutually orthogonal.  Thus, $\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2,\ldots,\mathbf{x}_r$ are eigenvectors associated to the eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_r$, respectively.  The lemma is now verified.

***Remark.*** We can say a bit more about the Jordan canonical form of $\mathbf{X}$.  First, note that $\ker(\mathbf{X})$ is $(n-m)$-dimensional.  As $\dim_\mathbb{K}\big(\ker(\mathbf{X}^t)\big)=n-r$ for all $t=2,3,\ldots$, we conclude that, for the eigenvalue $0$, $\mathbf{X}$ has $m-r$ Jordan blocks of size $2$ and $n+r-2m$ Jordan blocks of size $1$.  We can also see that $\mathbf{x}_{r+1},\mathbf{x}_{r+2},\ldots,\mathbf{x}_m\in\ker(\mathbf{X})\subseteq \ker(\mathbf{X}^2)=\ker(\mathbf{X}^3)=\ker(\mathbf{X}^4)=\ldots$.  Indeed, for each $k=r+1,r+2,\ldots,m$, the two vectors $\mathbf{x}_k$ and $\mathbf{w}_k$ are generalized eigenvectors for a Jordan block of $\mathbf{X}$.  You can then use the map $\boldsymbol{\varphi}:\mathbb{K}^n\to\mathbb{K}^{2m-r}$ sending $$\mathbf{v}\mapsto \big(\langle \mathbf{v},\mathbf{x}_1\rangle,\langle\mathbf{v},\mathbf{x}_2\rangle,\ldots,\langle\mathbf{v},\mathbf{x}_m\rangle,\langle\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}_{r+1}\rangle,\langle\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}_{r+2}\rangle,\ldots,\langle\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}_m\rangle\big)$$
for all $\mathbb{v}\in V$ and take $n+r-2m$ linearly independent vectors $\mathbf{y}_1,\mathbf{y}_2,\ldots,\mathbf{y}_{n+r-2m}\in \ker(\boldsymbol{\varphi})$.  Then, you have found  generalized eigenvectors of $\mathbf{X}$:
$$\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2,\ldots,\mathbf{x}_r,\mathbf{x}_{r+1},\mathbf{w}_{r+1},\mathbf{x}_{r+2},\mathbf{w}_{r+2},\ldots,\mathbf{x}_m,\mathbf{w}_m,\mathbf{y}_1,\mathbf{y}_2,\ldots,\mathbf{y}_{n+r-2m}\,.$$

---

In the case where $\mathbb{K}$ is a *symmetric subfield* of $\mathbb{C}$, that is $\mathbb{K}$ contains the complex conjugates of all its elements, we can use the same argument, except that $\langle\_,\_\rangle$ is replaced by the standard sesquilinear inner product on $\mathbb{C}^n$ and that the transpose operator $\top$ is replaced by the Hermitian operator $\dagger$.  In other words, we have the following corollary.

> **Corollary.**  Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a symmetric subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ and $n$ a positive integer.  For each   The vector field $V:=\mathbb{K}^n$ is equipped with the usual Hermitian form $\langle\_,\_\rangle$ defined by
>   $$\big\langle (u^1,u^2,\ldots,u^n),(v^1,v^2,\ldots,v^n)\big\rangle:=u_1\bar{v}_1+u_2\bar{v}_2+\ldots+u_n\bar{v}_n$$
>   for all $u^1,u^2,\ldots,u^n,v^1,v^2,\ldots,v^n\in\mathbb{K}$.  For a nonnegative integer $m$, suppose that $\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2,\ldots,\mathbf{x}_m$ are linearly independent vectors in $V$, which are *mutually orthogonal*, namely, $\langle \mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{x}_j\rangle =0$ for all $i,j\in\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$ with $i\neq j$.  Write $\lambda_k:=\langle \mathbf{x}_k,\mathbf{x}_k\rangle$ for $k=1,2,\ldots,m$.  Let $\xi_1,\xi_2,\ldots,\xi_m$ be arbitrary nonzero scalars (elements of $\mathbb{K}$).  Then, the matrix $$\mathbf{X}=\sum_{k=1}^m\,\xi_k\,\mathbf{x}_k\,\mathbf{x}_k^\dagger$$ is of rank $m$ with eigenvalues $\xi_1\lambda_1,\xi_2\lambda_2,\ldots,\xi_m\lambda_m,\underbrace{0,0,\ldots,0}_{n-m\text{ zeros}}$.

Unlike the lemma, all $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_m\in\mathbb{K}$ are positive real numbers (i.e., they cannot be $0$).  Thus, $\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2,\ldots,\mathbf{x}_m$ are all eigenvectors corresponding to the nonzero eigenvalues $\xi_1\lambda_1,\xi_2\lambda_2,\ldots,\xi_m\lambda_m$.  Plus, the linear map $\boldsymbol{\varphi}:\mathbb{K}^n\to\mathbb{K}^m$ sending $\mathbf{v}\mapsto\big(\langle\mathbf{v},\mathbf{x}_1\rangle,\langle\mathbf{v},\mathbf{x}_2\rangle,\ldots,\langle\mathbf{v},\mathbf{x}_m\rangle\big)$ for all $\mathbf{v}\in\mathbb{K}^n$ is of rank $m$, so there exist $n-m$ linearly independent elements $\mathbf{y}_1,\mathbf{y}_2,\ldots,\mathbf{y}_{n-m}$ in $\ker(\boldsymbol{\varphi})$.  Then, $\mathbf{y}_1,\mathbf{y}_2,\ldots,\mathbf{y}_{n-m}$ are $n-m$ linearly independent eigenvalues of $\mathbf{X}$ associated to the eigenvalue $0$.

---

**P.S.**  The matrix $\mathbf{B}$ as in the hint of the problem can be taken to be the $n$-by-$m$ matrix $$\mathbf{B}:=\begin{bmatrix}
{\rule[-1ex]{0.5pt}{2.5ex}} & {\rule[-1ex]{0.5pt}{2.5ex}} & & {\rule[-1ex]{0.5pt}{2.5ex}}\\
\textbf{x}_1&\textbf{x}_2&\cdots&\textbf{x}_m\\
{\rule[-1ex]{0.5pt}{2.5ex}} & {\rule[-1ex]{0.5pt}{2.5ex}} &  & {\rule[-1ex]{0.5pt}{2.5ex}}
\end{bmatrix}\,,$$ so that $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{B}\,\mathbf{D}\,\mathbf{B}^\top$ (or $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{B}\,\mathbf{D}\,\mathbf{B}^\dagger$ in the last part of my answer), where $\mathbf{D}$ is the $m$-by-$m$ diagonal matrix
$$\mathbf{D}:=\text{diag}\left(\xi_1,\xi_2,\ldots,\xi_m\right)\,.$$  You can see that $\mathbf{B}$ has full rank (i.e., $\text{rank}(\mathbf{B})=m$) and $\mathbf{B}^\top\,\mathbf{B}$ (or $\mathbf{B}^\dagger\, \mathbf{B}$ in the last part of my answer) is the $m$-by-$m$ diagonal matrix
$$\text{diag}\left(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_m\right)\,.$$

Comment: thanks  u @Batominovski